# Function signature that is an array

Tags: typescript

Should this work?

```
interface MyInterface{
}

class MyClass {
    DoSomething(callback: (MyInterface[]) => void) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The compiler doesn't like that the parameter is an array of MyInterface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing argument name:

```
interface MyInterface{
}

class MyClass {
    DoSomething(callback: (arg:MyInterface[]) => void) {
    }
}
```